# Cannot edit Sharepoint files on my mac.

Tags: macos, sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint on my mac. (tried both Safari and Chrome) Editing files online is not possible. Error: "Sorry, this document can't be opened for editing."
Tried .doc files and .docx files, both did not work.

Some files, made by colleagues can be opened, but the browser messes up the layout.

What to do?

Thanks!
Jill

Comment: This question is likely off topic for StackOverflow, since it doesn't relate to programming. You could ask it instead on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

How a file opens is determined by settings in the library. If the library does not allow the file to open in a browser view and you don't have the appropriate software in your machine then it won't open.

The browser view making a mess of document layouts is pretty much standard for MS file types in browser viewers. If you have ever wondered why developers tend to prefer text files in preference to MSWord and the like that's one of the many reasons.

There are so many more factors that may be causing what you are experiencing that it is impossible to work through them all in this context. Are you able to discuss what is happening for you with a Site Owner or Site Collection Owner and start exploring the Site Settings, the List Settings, the software on your machine, the formatting of the documents that are not displaying well in the browser and see if you can start eliminating obvious problems and collecting more facts that you can share with us to see if we can answer a focused question about some aspect of what your are experiencing.